# Which startup programs and services to disable

Tags: windows-7, laptop, msconfig

What I usually do is I go to `msconfig` and disable all startup programs, and all non-Microsoft services. But, I've heard an opinion that hardware manufacturers install additional software with the reason to avoid crashes and unstable work.

I do not know whether I should or can disable programs like:
Synaptics pointing device, Realtek HD Audio Manager, Intel Common User Interface, Dell Quickset, IAStorIcon, Adobe Acrobat, Microsoft Office 2010, etc.

Why does, for example, MS Office wants to start on computer load?
Is it safe to disable all applications?
Is it going to improve my performance?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/).

It will answer all those questions in detail.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. It's just a company website

Answer (score 0):

There is [Tuneup Utilities](http://www.tune-up.com/products/tuneup-utilities/) which has a start up manager. It'll show you list of all your startup programs and categorizes them in to three groups: necessary, unnecessary and optional. All startup programs will also have a brief description of what its functions are. See the screenshot below for preview of this feature.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, as far as I can see question is will removing applications from autorun improve preformance.

Well - yes and no.

OS will boot faster, but aplications which you removed from autorun will start slower or you might lose some features.
.
E.g. Part of MS OneNote can start with system and provide quick access to notes and acess to some... Hmmm, let's say "macros" (like OneNote's screenshot).

Also, if applications starts with your system, coldboot (starting aplication for the first time) time is reduced.

Answer (score -2):

In my humble opinion [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902), by Mark Russinovich and Bryce Cogswell, is really the definitive start-up inspector.

Comment: -1 While this is true, it's also not an answer to the question. They're *not* asking how to inspect the start up items, but *what they can or should remove*.

Answer (score -3):

Even if the question was asked two years ago, installing additional software, wasn't really a soloution for me.

After reading [this](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/371918/removing-msconfig-startup-list-items/?p=2083996) post I'd advise you (or the person that just googled the same issue) to cut down the start-up programs to "Synaptics pointing device" .

I hesitated doing this myself at first, but the truth ist that as important as things like "Intel Common User Interface" sound, they really just do you a bit of time saving when you really need them, which in intel's case is, if you change your graphic settings via the "intel Graphics and media control panel" in your taskbar.